# Write streaming data to GCS using Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How to write messages received from PubSub to a text file in GCS using TextIO in Apache Beam? Saw some methods like withWindowedWrites() and withFilenamePolicy() but couldn't find any example of it in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example provided you are using the Java SDK (BEAM 2.1.0).

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
                                                    .withValidation()
                                                    .as(PipelineOptions.class);

Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

pipeline.begin()
               .apply("PubsubIO",PubsubIO.readStrings()
                     .withTimestampAttribute("timestamp")
                     .fromSubscription("projects/YOUR-PROJECT/subscriptions/YOUR-SUBSCRIPTION"))
               .apply(Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30L))))
               .apply(TextIO.write().to("gs://YOUR-BUCKET").withWindowedWrites());
```

You can see the defaults that the SDK uses for the file naming by exploring the "expand" method in TextIO.Write.expand(PCollection input). Specifically I'd take a look at DefaultFilenamePolicy.java

Comment: Note that the call to setStreaming is unnecessary. And more importantly, you need to add some windowing to use withWindowedWrites.

Comment: I just read through StreamingOptions and I see that it defaults to true if the pipeline contains an Unbounded PCollection - Awesome!
I also have updated the code snippet to contain windowing logic and removed the redundant setStreaming configuration on the PipelineOptions.

Comment: What about if the name of the destination bucket depends on part of the input data? In the example, the data type is just <String>, but what if it were <String, SomeValue> where the first type parameter will be the name of the bucket its written to and the second type parameter will be a serializable class that you'd write to the bucket?