# Beam Pipeline (PY) Output not getting written to localhost disk

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm learning Windowing & Triggering concepts in Apache with the intention to:

- reads for unbounded sources (PubSub)
- write the incoming message to localhost disk every **5 sec FIXED Window interval**

ISSUE: no output getting written to localhost disk (the pipeline did create a *beam-team-* folder and wrote some files in there but no *output.csv* in intended destination getting written every 5 sec.)

- running apache-beam==2.9.0, Python 2.7.10
- Tried both: **DirectRunner**, as well as **DataFlowRunner** (with GCS Bucket as destination)

Here's the code (thanks a lot in advance for any advice):

```
p = beam.Pipeline(runner=None, options=options, argv=None)

"""
#1) Read incoming messages & apply Windowing
"""
lines = p | "read_sub" >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(topic=None, subscription=SUBSCRIBER, with_attributes=True) \


"""
#2) Apply 5 sec Windowing
"""
          | 'window' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(5))


"""
#3) apply Map() ops
"""
output = lines | "pardo" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.data)


"""
#4) write out to localhost disk
"""

output | beam.io.WriteToText('output', file_name_suffix='.csv', header='time, colname1, colname2')

p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

thanks a lot in advance for any advice!

Cheers!

Comment: When running with the direct runner, can you check the output in the console? Is there any relevant information there? Any errors?

Comment: no, nothing. only the deprecation warning: /Applications/py_venvs/dataflow_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py:365: BeamDeprecationWarning: options is deprecated since First stable release. References to <pipeline>.options will not be supported

Comment: Have you checked that there are no sharded files? something like output-0000-of-0010.csv ?

Comment: I checked already.. DIrectRunner only created a beam-temp-* directory where expected output files are dumped (temporarily?!).. but nothing gets output in expected output directory (__python pipeline.py --runner DirectRunner --input input.csv --output output --streaming__)

Comment: similar behaviour for Dataflow Runner as well, except for: it outputs sharded files but still in  __beam-temp-*__ directory.. nothing output in gs:// bucket location I passed as argument to beam.io.WriteToText()

Comment: __UPDATE__: DataflowRunner does writes the output to expected destination AFTER I cancel the job in GCP UI

Comment: hi, anyone, any further comments. I still haven't managed to resolve this.. looks a BUG to me (?!)

Answer (score 3):

You are reading from unbounded source and trying to write to a bounded source. While Beam API for Java supports it using [withWindowedWrites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909579/write-streaming-data-to-gcs-using-apache-beam) method, but its not supported in Python yet, which is a long awaited useful feature. So you need to either switch to java or write it to BigQuery.

Comment: won't applying Trggers AfterWatermark() solve? as per my understanding it should emit the result at each Window close and output to text file...

Comment: Unfortunately no. If you modify your write sink to pub/sub or bigquery, you will find that the triggering is working perfectly. Its just that python API does not support write to unbounded destination yet